# CSS block elements on a line

Tags: html, css, web-standards

What's the most common way to deal with a series of block elements that need to be on a line  (if javascript needs to be able to modify their widths, for example)? What are the pros and cons to applying float:left to each of them vs. using positioning to place them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating would be my choice, but it really depends on what you wish to achieve. If you can provide a more specific example I would be able to give you a clear reason as to what and why I think you should use. However here is a brief set of pros and cons that I have come accross (I'm assuming that by positioning you mean absolute positioning):

Positioning pros:

- very precise positioning in relation to the next ancestor marked as position relative - allows for great flexibility
- allows for elements to be in a different order visually than they are in the DOM

Positioning cons:

- Harder to line up with other elements since the positioned element is no longer in the document flow and also because of the level of precision required.
- Other elements ignore the absolutely positioned element which means you could have a potential overlap, unless you account for the minimum and maximum size of the positioned element
- harder to implement a footer if you are using absolute positioning for your columns.

Float pros:

- really easy to construct simple and advanced layouts
- no footer problem
- no worrying about precision, browser takes care of that for you
- parent container stretches

Float cons:

- Lots of pitfalls for those less experienced with float layouts that may lead to many questions being asked on SO :)

As to the clear:both element that Sebastian mentioned, There's a simple way around that. Lets say you have a container div and 2 floated divs inside.

Html:

```
<div id="con">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#con { background:#f0f; }
.float { float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background:#0ff; }
```

if you were to run this code you would notice that the container div (the magenta coloured one) is only a single pixel high whereas the floated divs were correct - which is the problem Sebastian mentioned. Now you could take his advice and add a br or float the container which would not be very semantic - so here is a slightly more elegant solution. Just add overflow:hidden; to the container div like so:

```
#con { background:#f0f; overflow:hidden; }
```

Now your container should wrap the floated divs properly.

Answer (score 10):

Well, if you're not too concerned with older browsers (I'm looking at you, IE6) the best way here is to go with

```
display:inline-block;
```

Basically, it creates a box-model element without clearing before or after it, so it remains in the line. Every modern browser interprets it well.

Comment: try firefox.. it also has issues with this property.. if I'm not mistake there is a -moz-inline-block or something for this..

Comment: Just today I did some stuff using it (FF3) and had no problems whatsoever, looked he same in FF, Opera, Chrome and IE7

Comment: Bad idea, there are simple ways to implement what he's talking about without using sketchy elements that aren't supported in many browsers (IE6 is still a major browser despite how we all feel about it)

Comment: IE6 can supoort it correctly with minor adaptations (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), but as many things in webdesign, the way to chose to solve a problem is directly related to the public of the site. That's why I said that he could use it if older browsers don't concern him.

Answer (score 1):

The parent container does not stretch with them unless it is also assigned a float tag or there is a br with clear:both; at the bottom.

I would go with the float:left instead of the positioning. The browser does all the aligning when one object stretches. So there is less for you to care about.

Answer (score 1):

I think i wouldn't explicitly position the elements but rather instruct the browser to use an inline layout for the elements using display:inline and let the browser handle the positioning.

regarding float vs positioning i think the only way to line them up using positioning is by using absolute positioning, and that means you need to handle re-sizes(of the browser view port) in order to keep the elements in place.

I think that by using the float property the browser handles the re-sizing issues for you and re-renders the element in the correct place.

Comment: The problem with display:inline is it precludes a lot of options for scripting, including dynamically resizing width.

Answer (score 0):

Only disadvantage to float in situations like this for me has been that you'll either need to left justify them or right justify them -- centering is not an option.  However you've mentioned you're using absolute values for widths, so you could just nest all the floated elements in a DIV element and add either margin-right or margin-left to the parent DIV to simulate center alignment.